# Keep changes synchronized between 2 repositories with same branch names

Tags: git

We have 2 git repositories on different servers and until now the team has first made changes to the first and then the same changes to the second. How can we push the changes automatically (also overwriting changes) from the 1 to the 2nd repository? We have a list of the branches we want synched so we would need a command that specifies the branches to get fetched and pushed to the 2nd repo.

This is what we have created until now, but we get errors when overwriting and also need to fetch/push specific branches:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/org/repo-1.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://host.com/org/repo-2
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror
```

Comment: That should work. Note that mirror clones are pretty specialized and pushing to a mirror like this is usually not a great idea; it's better to set up a read-only mirror clone on a slave-server and have that server do its own `git fetch -p` or `git remote update --prune` via a crontab entry or similar.

Answer (score 0):

as it is on github you should fork your first repo and provide changes to through pull requests